# Force SMS Verification At Every Login

Tags: login, sms

I want to force SMS Verification at every login. However it only seems to prompt periodically (cookies), I do not have any IP ranges defined. What setting is needed to force SMS verification (or email) at every login?

"Enable the SMS method of identity verification" is enabled in session settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Identity Verification is only when a user logs in from an untrusted location from an untrusted device. If you want to force some sort of two-factor authentication, you need to [Require Two-Factor Authentication](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_require_two_factor_authentication.htm&type=0). You can't force SMS verification without custom coding, but [Two-Factor Authentication](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.206.0.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/security_overview_2fa.htm) explains further about how 2FA operates in salesforce.

> You can set policies that require a second level of authentication on every login, every login through the API (for developers and client applications), or for access to specific features. Your users can provide the second factor by downloading and installing a mobile authenticator app, such as the Salesforce Authenticator app or the Google Authenticator app, on their mobile device. They can also use a U2F security key as the second factor. After they connect an authenticator app or register a security key with their account in Salesforce, they use them whenever your org’s policies require two-factor authentication.
>
> The Salesforce Authenticator mobile app (version 2 and later) sends a push notification to the user’s mobile device when activity on the Salesforce account requires identity verification. The user responds on the mobile device to verify or block the activity. The user can enable location services for the app and automate verifications from trusted locations, such as a home or office. Salesforce Authenticator also generates verification codes, sometimes called “time-based one-time passwords” (TOTPs). Users can choose to enter a password plus the code instead of responding to a push notification from the app for two-factor verification. Or they can get a verification code from another authenticator app.

SMS isn't explicitly supported for 2FA out of the box, but [this article](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/SMS-2FA) explains how to use a third-party SMS service to enable 2FA over SMS. It's a bit too lengthy to go in to details here, but the link fully explains the process for setting up 2FA SMS via a Login Flow.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I was hoping for another solution, my users will hate having to download an App just for this. I may use a third party  service.

Comment: @RobertE.Lee Yeah, the last link has an article that explains how to integrate with Twilio to get the desired results. It does require some code, but it's mostly copy-paste.